# php multi feed rss parser?

Tags: php, rss

Are there any scripts or classes available in PHP that can allow me to define different RSS feeds to have them output on a page ordered by date?

I want a page that will have RSS feeds parsed from multiple source bundled together but sorted by date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One script that can do this is [*SimplePie*](http://simplepie.org/). See [Sort multiple feeds by time and date](http://simplepie.org/wiki/tutorial/sort_multiple_feeds_by_time_and_date).

```
// Create a new SimplePie object
$feed = new SimplePie();

// Instead of only passing in one feed url, we'll pass in an array of three
$feed->set_feed_url(array(
    'http://digg.com/rss/index.xml',
    'http://feeds.tuaw.com/weblogsinc/tuaw',
    'http://feeds.uneasysilence.com/uneasysilence/blog'
));

// Initialize the feed object
$feed->init();

// This will work if all of the feeds accept the same settings.
$feed->handle_content_type();

foreach ($feed->get_items() as $item) {
    $item->get_title(), "\n"; 
}
```